# How to convert long or string to date format (like HH:mm:ss) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, casting

I have a array of objects as below,

```
...
{"key_as_string": "14:11:00", //string type
 "key": 1529579460000,    // key_as_string date of type 
 "doc_count": 25
 },
...
```

How to convert date type `HH:mm:ss` from `key_as_string` or `key`?

Comment: Look into moment.js

Comment: Is there solution without framework ?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. It may help if you provided an example. ie, “im trying to convert X to Y”.

Comment: you mean you want it as a JS `Date` object? Since you only provide a time, should we assume the date should be the current date when the code executes, or some other specific date?

Comment: Okey, I have date value  in "key_as_string" but its type string not date.  And javascript want to be time type. Or I have long value  in "key". And I try to convert date to long. Actually, i have two questions

Comment: there's no "Time" type in JavaScript, only Date (which can include time). So please answer my question regarding what to set as the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var timeFromJSON = JSONName.key_as_string;

var hours = timeFromJSON.split(':')[0];
var minutes = timeFromJSON.split(':')[1];
var seconds = timeFromJSON.split(':')[2];

var date = new Date(0, 0, 0, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

And now you could do something like this:

```
date.getHours();   // Expected output: 14
date.getMinutes(); // Expected output: 11
date.getSeconds(); // Expected output: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var long_date=1529579460000;
var date = new Date(long_date);
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
var out_date = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
console.log(out_date);
```